# Android Using Multiple methods inside Asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to run a background asynctask to load in my data.
I have 2 methods that load in data and I'm running them in an `AsyncTask`.
When it's done loading I have a method called `Filldata` that fills the UI with the data.

The problem is at the moment it's only filling the UI with whichever method finishes downloading the data first.
Is there a way to run multiple methods inside one `AsyncTask` or do I need multiple `AsyncTasks`?

Here's my `AsyncTask`

```
public class PostTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        boolean result = false;
        loadNewsFeed();
        loadResultsFeed();
        publishProgress("progress");
        return result;
    }


    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 1; i < progress.length; i++) {
                str.append(progress[i] + " ");

            }
    }

        @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.v("BGThread", "begin fillin data");
         FillData();
    }
}
```

heres my full code

```
public void checkPreferences(){

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ChosenMethod = preferences.getString("ChosenMethod", ChosenMethod);
        ChosenLeagueID = preferences.getString("ChosenLeagueId", ChosenLeagueID);
        ChosenTeamId = preferences.getString("ChosenTeamId", ChosenTeamId);

         Log.v("lc", "newsurl" + newsFeedURL);


        Log.v("myapp", "ChosenMethod Home = " + ChosenMethod);
        Log.v("myapp", "ChosenLeagueID Home = " + ChosenLeagueID);
        Log.v("myapp", "ChosenTeamID Home = " + ChosenTeamId);

         if (ChosenMethod.equals("Team")) {
             setContentView(R.layout.homeactteam2);
             newsAmount = 5;

         } else {
             newsAmount = 10;
             setContentView(R.layout.homeactteam);
         }

}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Check Preferences which sets UI

    checkPreferences();
   PostTask posttask;
   posttask = new PostTask();
   posttask.execute();




    Button backbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backbtn);

    //Listening to button event
    backbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //Starting a new Intent
            Intent previousScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChooseTeamActivity.class);
            ChosenMethod = "null";
            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString("ChosenMethod", ChosenMethod);            
            editor.commit();
            previousScreen.putExtra("FullData", fulldata);
            startActivity(previousScreen);


        }
    });

//((PullToRefreshListView) getListView()).setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {
//   
//    public void onRefresh() {
//        // Do work to refresh the list here.
//        loadData();
//    }
//});
//


}



public void loadNewsFeed(){

     newsFeedRequest = "" + chosenLeagueId + "" + unixTimeStamp;
     newsFeedURL = "" + newsFeedRequest;    

        String myhash = buildHmacSignature(apiKey, newsFeedURL);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(newsFeedURL);

        List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("requestToken", myhash));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("apiUser", apiUser));

            try {
                post.setEntity (new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
                String json = reader.readLine();
                fulldata = String.valueOf(json);
                Log.v("myApp","newsdata" + fulldata);

                newsList = new ArrayList<String>();
                newsList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
                newsList3 = new ArrayList<String>();
                imageList = new ArrayList<String>();


                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);    
                JSONObject objData = obj.getJSONObject("data");
                JSONArray jArray = objData.getJSONArray("news");
                Log.v("lc","newsAmount= " + newsAmount);

                   for(int t = 0; t < newsAmount; t++){
                       JSONObject newsTitleDict = jArray.getJSONObject(t);
                       imageList.add(newsTitleDict.getString("image_small"));
                     newsList3.add(newsTitleDict.getString("title"));

                   }

                   for(int t = 0; t < 1; t++){
                       JSONObject newsTitleDict = jArray.getJSONObject(t);

                 newsList.add(newsTitleDict.getString("title"));
            //       newsList2.add(newsTitleDict.getString("title"));

                   }

                     Log.v("BGThread", "Loaded news");
                     loadResultsFeed();

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}           


public void loadResultsFeed(){


    resultsFeedRequest = "" + chosenLeagueId + "" + ChosenTeamId + "" + unixTimeStamp;
    resultsFeedURL = "https://secure.pitchero.com/_services/api/" + resultsFeedRequest; 

    String myhash = buildHmacSignature(apiKey, resultsFeedURL);

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(resultsFeedURL);

    List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("requestToken", myhash));
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("apiUser", apiUser));

    try {
        post.setEntity (new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        String json = reader.readLine();
        fulldata = String.valueOf(json);
        Log.v("myApp","resultsdata" + fulldata);

        newsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        newsList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        newsList3 = new ArrayList<String>();
        imageList = new ArrayList<String>();


        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);    
        JSONObject objData = obj.getJSONObject("data");
        JSONArray jArray = objData.getJSONArray("results");


        if(jArray.length() < 1) loadLastResults();

        for(int t = 0; t < 1; t++){

               resultsDict = jArray.getJSONObject(t);
              HomeTeam = resultsDict.getString("hometeam");
              AwayTeam = resultsDict.getString("awayteam");
              HomeScore = resultsDict.getString("homescore");
              AwayScore = resultsDict.getString("awayscore");
              Attendance = resultsDict.getString("attendance");
              Division = resultsDict.getString("division");

              Log.v("lc","hometeam" + HomeTeam);
              Log.v("lc","awayteam" + AwayTeam);

             Log.v("BGThread", "Loaded results");

           }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   


}


public void loadLastResults(){

    resultsFeedRequest = "" + chosenLeagueId + "" + ChosenTeamId + "&limit=31&timestamp=" + unixTimeStamp;
    resultsFeedURL = "" + resultsFeedRequest;   

     String myhash = buildHmacSignature(apiKey, resultsFeedURL);

    Date anotherCurDate = new Date();  
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");  
    String CurMonth = formatter.format(anotherCurDate);  

    int Int = Integer.parseInt(CurMonth);

    int MonthInt = Int -1;


    CurMonth = (String) (String.valueOf(MonthInt));



    if (CurMonth.equals("1")){

        lastMonth = "12";

    }    
     else {
        if(CurMonth.length() < 2){
            lastMonth = "0" + CurMonth;
        } else {
            lastMonth = CurMonth;
        }
    }

    Log.v("lc","month= " + CurMonth);
    Log.v("lc","LastMonth= " + lastMonth);


        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(resultsFeedURL);

        List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("requestToken", myhash));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("apiUser", apiUser));

        try {
            post.setEntity (new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            String json = reader.readLine();
            fulldata = String.valueOf(json);
            Log.v("myApp","resultsdata" + fulldata);

            newsList = new ArrayList<String>();
            newsList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
            newsList3 = new ArrayList<String>();
            imageList = new ArrayList<String>();


            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);    
            JSONObject objData = obj.getJSONObject("data");
            JSONArray jArray = objData.getJSONArray("results");


               for(int t = 0; t < 1; t++){

                   resultsDict = jArray.getJSONObject(t);
                  HomeTeam = resultsDict.getString("hometeam");
                  AwayTeam = resultsDict.getString("awayteam");
                  HomeScore = resultsDict.getString("homescore");
                  AwayScore = resultsDict.getString("awayscore");
                  Attendance = resultsDict.getString("attendance");
                  Division = resultsDict.getString("division");

                  Log.v("lc","hometeam" + HomeTeam);
                  Log.v("lc","awayteam" + AwayTeam);

                 Log.v("BGThread", "Loaded Last results");

               }


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }   


public class PostTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        boolean result = false;

        loadNewsFeed();
        publishProgress("method1_complete");
        loadResultsFeed();
        publishProgress("method2_complete");
        return result;
    }


    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 1; i < progress.length; i++) {
                str.append(progress[i] + " ");

            }
    }

        @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.v("BGThread", "begin fillin data");
         FillData();
    }
}



public void FillData(){ 


     if (ChosenMethod.equals("Team")) {




        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.single_item, newsList);

         String[] mStrings = (String[]) imageList.toArray(new String[imageList.size()]);
         String[] news = (String[]) newsList3.toArray(new String[newsList3.size()]);

         arrayAdapter3 = new LazyAdapter(this, mStrings, news);


            ListView list = getListView();
               list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

               LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
                View header = inflater.inflate( R.layout.homeheader, list, false);
                View header2 = inflater.inflate( R.layout.homeheader2, list, false);
                View header3 = inflater.inflate( R.layout.homeheader3, list, false);


        //setListAdapter (arrayAdapter);

                 resultsView = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.resultscell,
                         null);

               TextView homeTeam = (TextView) resultsView.findViewById(R.id.HomeTeam);
               homeTeam.setText(HomeTeam);

               TextView awayTeam = (TextView) resultsView.findViewById(R.id.AwayTeam);
               awayTeam.setText(AwayTeam);

               TextView homeScore = (TextView) resultsView.findViewById(R.id.HomeScore);
               homeScore.setText(HomeScore);

               TextView awayScore = (TextView) resultsView.findViewById(R.id.AwayScore);
               awayScore.setText(AwayScore);

               TextView attendance = (TextView) resultsView.findViewById(R.id.Attendence);
               attendance.setText("Att:" + Attendance);

               TextView division = (TextView) resultsView.findViewById(R.id.Division);
               division.setText(Division);

               Log.v("BGThread", "Filled results");

            adapter = new MergeAdapter();
            adapter.addView(header);
            adapter.addAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            adapter.addView(header2);
            adapter.addView(resultsView);
            adapter.addView(header3);
            adapter.addAdapter(arrayAdapter3);
            setListAdapter(adapter);

            Log.v("BGThread", "Filled Merge Adapter Team");

     } else {

         arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.single_item, newsList);
            arrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.single_item, newsList2);
            //arrayAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.complex_item, newsList3);

             String[] mStrings = (String[]) imageList.toArray(new String[imageList.size()]);
             String[] news = (String[]) newsList3.toArray(new String[newsList3.size()]);


             arrayAdapter3 = new LazyAdapter(this, mStrings, news);


                ListView list = getListView();
                   list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

                   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
                    View header3 = inflater.inflate( R.layout.homeheader3, list, false);


            //setListAdapter (arrayAdapter);


                adapter = new MergeAdapter();
                adapter.addView(header3);
                adapter.addAdapter(arrayAdapter3);
                setListAdapter(adapter);

                Log.v("BGThread", "Filled Merge Adapter League");
         } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both methods will be executed sequentially, because they're in one `AsyncTask`: first `loadNewsFeed()` will be executed, then if that's finished, `loadResultsFeed()` is executed.

So viewing your code example, there's no evidence of one or more methods not being executed.

Comment: why do you think its only showing one of them for example if i comment out loadResultsFeed() all the news stories load but the results don't. however when uncommented only the results show?

Answer (score 1):

You can have following Logic (Not Tested!)

```
 loadNewsFeed();
 publishProgress("method1_complete");
 loadResultsFeed();
 publishProgress("method2_complete");

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... values)
    {
        if(values[0].toString().equalsIgnoreCase("method1_complete"))
        {
            fill ui from method 1
        }
        else
        {
            fill ui from method 2
        }
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
```

Below is sample snippet.

```
class abc extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>
    {

        int i, j;
        Context context;

        public abc(AActivity aActivity)
        {
            this.context = aActivity;
        }

        public void method1()
        {
            i = 1;
        }

        public void method2()
        {
            j = 2;
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params)
        {

            method1();
            publishProgress("method1");
            method2();
            publishProgress("method2");

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... values)
        {
            if (values[0].toString().equalsIgnoreCase("method1"))
            {
                EditText text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);
                text1.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            } else
            {
                EditText text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text2);
                text2.setText(String.valueOf(j));
            }
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

    }
```

Comment: will this load both at the same time not one over the other?